# How to use indexOf to find function in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I have an array of functions.

```
var arrOfFunc = [];
```

I have script that pushes to the array, a function that redraws a google chart

There can be multiple functions depending on how many graphs i decide to put on the page

```
var chart = "done";

function drawChart(){ ... } //each draw chart function belongs to its own scope.

arrOfFunc.push(drawChart);

$(window).resize(function(){
   if(chart=="done"){
     chart = "waiting";
     setTimeout(function(){
       for(var i in arrOfFunc ){
         arrOfFunc[i]();
       }
       chart = "done"
     },1000);
});
```

The problem is i have a refresh button for the grid that reruns the whole function that:

- makes the api call
- rerenders the grid with `drawChart()`
- than pushes the drawChart() function to arrOfFunc;

How can i check to see if the function already exists inside the array before deciding whether to push it to the arrOfFunc object?

Or does `.indexOf()` only work for strings.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Create a MCVE.

Comment: Not sure you can do that. You could give a name to each function and store those in another array.

Comment: `indexOf` works for any data type. `arrOfFunc.indexOf(drawChart) > -1`

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf); try it out.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have one `drawGraph` and give each graph an `id` that you use to render it? Like `drawGraph(0); drawGraph(1); drawGraph(4324);`

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` identifies the object in the array.

Since Javascript treats all the functions as objects, `indexOf` should work on functions too.

Answer (score 0):

It's against the fundamentals of JS to make multiple `drawChart()` functions. You just declare it once and invoke it from any object. The "`this`" that you should have referred within the function will represent the object that you are invoking it from. You best study the `this` and scoping in JS. I would suggest you to have a look at [this](https://www.quora.com/How-does-JavaScript-this-work/answer/%C3%96mer-Ka%C5%9Fdarma?srid=01By)